# Sitecore datasource query by date RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, sitecore

So I have this query:

query:$home//*[@@name='blogs']//*[@@templatename='BlogArticle' and contains(@date, '202208')]

It works fine, but my goal is to compare the value of the @date field to the current date. Is there a way to get the current date in Sitecore?

My goal is to have something like this:
query:$home//*[@@name='blogs']//*[@@templatename='BlogArticle' and @date >= @_currentdate - 2

I would like to be able to compare blog publishing dates to the current date and make sure they were published in the last 2 months.

Currently, Sitecore is pulling up to the RSS Feed limit of 50 and then sorting by date. (Hence not getting the most recent blogs published).

Or is there a better way? I'm open to any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it:

1. increase item limit and then
2. customize rss feed in c# and filter records based on date, e.g. of customization: https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2020/6/creating-and-customizing-an-rss-feed-in-sitecore